# Authentication to Upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: 14.04

Running 14.04. Prompted to upgrade to 16.04, when I agree it asks for an Authentication password. What's this, and where is it?

Comment: It is your password.

Answer (score 0):

Its asking your system password what you have provided at the time of installing ubuntu or getting started with ubuntu. If you are owner then you should know what is your password. It will just verify that whether the owner wants to upgrade or any other is trying do so. Its just a step to another step to secure your system.vote up if you got it.